# USB Audio interface with Google Pixel 3a

Tags: usb, audio, google-pixel

I just migrated to a Google Pixel 3a coming from an old iPhone and I realized that I can't use my USB external audio interface for recording videos with my new phone.

I used my Zoom UR-24 without any problems with an old iPhone 5s

It's a shame, because one of the main reasons to migrate was the camera quality and for recording videos with external audio.

Is there any usb soundcard compatible with Android/Google Pixel ?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some options:

- Use an alternative camera app, which will allow you to set the audio source. For example: [Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera)
- Record the audio in a separate app then edit the audio and video together later. An example app for recording audio from your interface is [USB Audio Recorder PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.extreamsd.usbaudiorecorderpro&hl=en_US)

Also, since this question is a top hit for "Pixel USB Audio Class 3", I want to also mention that the Pixel 3a *does not* support USB Audio Class 3.0. This means that unlike the Pixel 2, it *does not* support more than audio interfaces with more than 2 channels. I learned this by calling the [Google's product specialists](https://store.google.com/magazine/consultation_virtual).